# Extracting text from a specific area of a PDF without OCR

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

I'm building an application that extracts text from specific regions of a PDF (i.e. Client name or client ID from PDFs that follow fixed layouts). For that, I have the user select the area with their mouse and the application takes that snippet away an applies OCR on it.

Although the results are satisfying, it's not 100% reliable.

With that in mind, is there a better way to do this?

I searched for solutions on the web using iText but most use a deprecated (iTextSharp) or outdated version of the library.

From the comments, I got this bit of code:

```
    static string ReadPDF()
    {
        string path = "PATH TO FILE";

        //Coordinates for the rectangle that contains the person's name written on the PDF document
        int[] upper_left = {118, 116};
        int[] lower_right = {582, 135};

        int width = lower_right[0] - upper_left[0];
        int height = lower_right[1] - upper_left[1];

        PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(path));
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(upper_left[0], upper_left[1], width, height);

        FilteredTextEventListener filterListener = new FilteredTextEventListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), new TextRegionEventFilter(rect));

        return PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(doc.GetPage(1), filterListener);
    }
```

The coordinates were the ones I used to extract the client's name from the file with OCR, which worked. I don't know what might be wrong with the code above.

Comment: *"I searched for solutions on the web using iText but most use a deprecated (iTextSharp) or outdated version of the library."* - Which version of iText do you want to use? The current 7.1.x? The latest 5.5.x?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to point that out. I'm using the current 7.1.7

Comment: You might be interested in this example - https://github.com/itext/itext7/blob/develop/kernel/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/canvas/parser/FilteredTextEventListenerTest.java

Comment: Thanks! I extracted the lines I thought were important from that example and created a method, which I posted above. Sadly it doesn't work.

Comment: *"The coordinates were the ones I used to extract the client's name from the file with OCR, which worked."* - The problem are the coordinates: PDFs use a coordinate system with the origin (usually) in the *bottom* left corner and the **y** coordinate increasing upwards while for bitmap images you often have a coordinate system with the origin in the top left and the **y** increasing downwards. Furthermore, bitmap image coordinates often use pixels as units while PDFs use the point as unit (1 pt = 1/72 in).Thus, you have to transform the coordinates.

Comment: It worked ! Thank you very much !
There were 2 problems:
-Bitmap pixels and coordinate origin transformation to PDF points and coordinate origin
-The PDF turned out to be rotated 90

For the Bitmap to PDF transformation: points = 1.33 * inches * 72
(72 points in an inch, 1.33 pixels in a point)

Now for the rotation and change in coordinate origin, I just found the X and Y of the lower left vertex of the rectangle, in respect to the PDF origin.

Comment: Great! Shall I make my comment an answer or do you want to explain?

Comment: You can make your comment the answer. I tried doing it myself but I couldn't find out how. I'm new to asking questions on stack. Thanks again !

Comment: I added my comment as an answer. You may mark it as accepted (by clicking on the tick under the voting arrows at its upper left).

Answer (score 0):

> The coordinates were the ones I used to extract the client's name from the file with OCR, which worked.

The problem are the coordinates:

- PDFs use a coordinate system with the origin (usually) in the bottom left corner and the **y** coordinate increasing upwards;
- for bitmap images you often have a coordinate system with the origin in the top left and the **y** increasing downwards.

Furthermore, bitmap image coordinates often use pixels as units while PDFs use the point as unit (1 pt = <sup>1</sup>/<sub>72</sub> in).

Thus, you have to transform the coordinates.

You actually found another complication yourself:

> The PDF turned out to be rotated 90

Indeed, each page in a PDF can have a **Rotate** entry which you can retrieve via `PdfPage.GetRotation()` and also have to take into account for the coordinate transformation.